# Filter xml file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, filter

I am trying to rebuild an old application without the loss of data. The current data has all been stored in xml files that i am trying to read using Javascript.

This is the Javascript (i'm new to this, feedback is appreciated):

```
// Create a connection to the file.
            var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Define which file to open and
            // send the request.
            Connect.open("GET", "writers.xml", false);
            Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            Connect.send(null);

            // Place the response in an XML document.
            var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML;

            // Place the root node in an element.
            var Customers = TheDocument.childNodes[0];

            // Retrieve each customer in turn.
            for (var i = 0; i < Customers.children.length; i++){
                var Customer = Customers.children[i];
                //Create div's for data
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='who" + i + "'></div>"
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='age" + i + "'></div>"
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='hobby" + i + "'></div>"
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='image" + i + "'></div>"
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='something" + i + "'></div>"
                //Assign data to correct divs
                var who = Customer.getElementsByTagName("name");
                var who2 = who[0].textContent.toString();
                document.getElementById("who"+i).innerHTML += who2;

                var age = Customer.getElementsByTagName("age");
                var age2 = age[0].textContent.toString();
                document.getElementById("age"+i).innerHTML += age2;

                var hobby = Customer.getElementsByTagName("hobby");
                var hobby2 = hobby[0].textContent.toString();
                document.getElementById("hobby"+i).innerHTML += hobby2;

                var image = Customer.getElementsByTagName("image");
                var image2 = image[0].textContent.toString();
                document.getElementById("image"+i).innerHTML += image2;

                var something = Customer.getElementsByTagName("something");
                var something2 = something[0].textContent.toString();
                document.getElementById("something"+i).innerHTML += something2;
            }
```

This is an example of my xml file:

```
<doc>
<person>
    <name>Paul</name>
    <age>21</age>
    <hobby>blabla</hobby>
    <image>thisisanimage.jpg</image>
    <something>Random string</something>
</person>
<person>
    <name>Peter</name>
    <age></age>
    <hobby>blabla</hobby>
    <image>thisisanimage.jpg</image>
    <something>Random string</something>
</person>
</doc>
```

Now i am trying to filter Peter out, because the age field is empty. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a condition in the loop, to test if the age is blank. If the age value is blank then the `if` block will not be entered, and the next iteration of the loop will start.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Customers.children.length; i++) {
    var Customer = Customers.children[i];

    var age = Customer.getElementsByTagName("age");
    var age2 = age[0].textContent.toString();

    if (age2 != '') { // only do the below code if age2 is not blank

        //Create div's for data
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='who" + i + "'></div>"
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='age" + i + "'></div>"
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='hobby" + i + "'></div>"
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='image" + i + "'></div>"
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id='something" + i + "'></div>"

        document.getElementById("age" + i).innerHTML += age2;

        //Assign data to correct divs
        var who = Customer.getElementsByTagName("name");
        var who2 = who[0].textContent.toString();
        document.getElementById("who" + i).innerHTML += who2;

        var hobby = Customer.getElementsByTagName("hobby");
        var hobby2 = hobby[0].textContent.toString();
        document.getElementById("hobby" + i).innerHTML += hobby2;

        var image = Customer.getElementsByTagName("image");
        var image2 = image[0].textContent.toString();
        document.getElementById("image" + i).innerHTML += image2;

        var something = Customer.getElementsByTagName("something");
        var something2 = something[0].textContent.toString();
        document.getElementById("something" + i).innerHTML += something2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, how did i not think of this. could not get any easier.